get-policy state not returning correct display name instead returning guid
'
subscriptionId = 'abc'
$nonCompliantPolicies = Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId 
# Define a custom object for each non-compliant resource
$customObjects = $nonCompliantPolicies | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PolicyName = $_.PolicyDefinitionName
        ComplianceState = $_.ComplianceState
        ResourceType = $_.ResourceType
        ResourceGroup = $_.ResourceGroup
        SubscriptionId = $_. subscriptionId
        IsCompliant    = $_.IsCompliant 
        PolicyAssignmentScope =$_.PolicyAssignmentScope
    }
}
 
# Export the custom objects to a CSV file
 
$customObjects | Format-Table -AutoSize

'
Policy name is generating GUID value but i need descriptive name kinldy provide a solution as how i can modify my code to get descriptive name of the policies rather than guid id

$subscriptionId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"

$policyStates = Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# $nonCompliantPolicies

$customObjects = $policyStates | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PolicyDefinitionName = $(Get-AzPolicyDefinition -Id $_.PolicyDefinitionId).Properties.DisplayName
        PolicyAssignmentName = $(Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Id $_.PolicyAssignmentId).Properties.DisplayName
        ComplianceState = $_.ComplianceState
        ResourceType = $_.ResourceType
        ResourceGroup = $_.ResourceGroup
        SubscriptionId = $_. subscriptionId
        IsCompliant    = $_.IsCompliant 
        PolicyAssignmentScope =$_.PolicyAssignmentScope
    }
}

$customObjects | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File xx.txt

Policy definition name may be different from policy assignment name sometimes, so need also include both to show more infomations.

Getting below error :Get-AzPolicyDefinition : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.
At line:8 char:34

... tionName = $(Get-AzPolicyDefinition -Id $_.PolicyDefinitionId).Proper ...

             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzPolicyDefinition], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Get-AzPolicyDefinition




I have just re-run it not throw error. I am using Az module 11.6 with powershell 7. If you do not want to upgrade your module or powershell. Just combine your code with Get-AzPolicyDefinition and Get-AzPolicyAssignment to dig-out the displayname from id

for below script as well dispaly name is coming as blank :
0
$resourceGroupName = "az-dna-xxxxx-test"
$roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
foreach ($assignment in $roleAssignments) {
Write-Host "DisplayName: $($assignment.DisplayName)"

Write-Host "Role Definition Name: $($assignment.RoleDefinitionName)"

Write-Host "Scope: $($assignment. Scope)"

}


get-policy state not returning correct display name instead returning guid

The Get-AzPolicyState command will display the policy definition name as a GUID instead of the descriptive name
To get the names using the policy definition GUID, you can use the script below to retrieve the policy definition names from the GUID.

$subId = "SUB_ID"

$NonCompliantPolicies = Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$customObjects = @()
foreach ($policy in $nonCompliantPolicies) {
    $policyDefName = $policy.PolicySetDefinitionName
   
    $policyDefinitions = Get-AzPolicyDefinition -Name $policyDefName

    $customObjects += [PSCustomObject]@{
        PolicyName = $policyDefinitions.DisplayName
        ComplianceState = $policy.ComplianceState
        ResourceType = $policy.ResourceType
        ResourceGroup = $policy.ResourceGroup
        SubscriptionId = $policy.SubscriptionId
        IsCompliant = $policy.IsCompliant
        PolicyAssignmentScope = $policy.PolicyAssignmentScope
    }
}

$customObjects | Format-Table -AutoSize

$customObjects | Export-Csv -Path "NonCompliantPoliciesreport.csv" -NoTypeInformation



Note: If the script above throws an error when executing it locally, please run it in Azure Cloud Shell.

Output

Excel Output

